# WSO2 API Manager - Thumbnail Images

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

What is the best way to set a default image for every API? I also want to prevent users from uploading their own images.

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends on exactly what you want to do it and what version of API Manager you are running. For example, if the image is clickable and how big the image is to be.  So I would recommend using google chrome and right click on the things you want to change and go down to inspect element. That way you can view the files and code you want to alter.

**To change default image**

I went to [APIM]/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/libs/theme-wso2_1.0/css/ directory and edited the theme-wso2.css file. I edited the element style of line 9681 (right below Thumbnail icon customizations in API Manager 2.1.0) here is the code

```
.thumbnail.icon {
  position: relative;
  content:  url(link to image); --Added this line
  max-width: 100% --Added this line
}
```

Do the same thing in the publisher directory.

**To remove option to upload image**

Go to [APIM]/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/themes/wso2/libs/theme-wso2_1.0/css/ and edit the theme-wso2.css. Edit line 1495 like below

```
.col-sm-offset-3 {
   margin-left: 25%;
   visibility: hidden; -- added line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieve by using sub-theme rather than modifying theme files directly as suggested above cause  and it is better you can mention the version of API Manager that you are using.

[Adding a New API Store Theme](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme#AddingaNewAPIStoreTheme-Savingdirectlyintothefilesystem)